# how to replace pagination previous and next buttons with images in angular?

Tags: angularjs, pagination

here is my html code for pagination , i am not getting how would i replace the next and previous buttons with the images , it is not even showing next and previous buttons in the html code itself , i have used the pagination tag to create a pagination , it is working fine but i need to replace the previous and next text with the images ,kindly help.

```
 <pagination page="currentPage" max-size="noOfPages" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="entryLimit">

                            </pagination>
```

my pagination control js

// pagination controls

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.totalLeadItems = $scope.finalLeadData.dataval;
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.finalLeadData.dataval.length;
        $scope.entryLimit = 2; // items per page
        $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);

        // $watch search to update pagination
        $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
          $scope.filtered = $filter($scope.finalLeadData.dataval, newVal);
          $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
          $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
          $scope.currentPage = 1;
        }, true);
      });
```

i am providing a plunker link for it :

```
 http://plnkr.co/edit/NZulJq4v8Hcl6O3AL4hw?p=preview
```

Comment: you should provide a plunker so it would be easier to help.
but generally speaking ui.bootstrap pagination directive renders html... you can add a class and then do with basic css .className>li>a:first-child,.className>li>a:last-child{background:url(myImage)}... given a url we can help better but that would be the direction I would take

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NZulJq4v8Hcl6O3AL4hw?p=preview

Comment: i have provided the link in the link kindly tell me how to append image into the place of "<" and ">" arrows into the pagination, bcz i donno whether it is possible to place images there or not

Comment: the documentation for the [pagination control](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) describes how to replace the ***text*** of the arrows; theoretically you could replace the text with markup....

Comment: i want to replace the text or arrows with image , what does mark up here means??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anky, I made a small fix to your plunker.
I just added an image from the web, just change to whatever you want ok?

here is the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yI5d6iR11KldVfAawJR8?p=preview)

as you can see I located the css in `<style>` tags, you just put it in your css

the css:

```
.pagination-test>li:first-child>a, .pagination-test>li:last-child>a{
    background: url(http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/7e81c2f3697b91ee17fe6ed6348c232a-Arrow.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
```

and the html:

```
        <pagination page="currentPage" max-size="noOfPages" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-test"previous-text="" next-text=""></pagination>
```

hope this is what you wanted

Comment: thank you jony it is exactly what i need u saved my day

Comment: feel free to mark as answered so others will know :)

Comment: @Jony-Y I can not set the next-text="" and previous-text="". Any revise?

Comment: @Kramer what about setting in the css color: transparent? that way you will not see the text. beyond that I cant think of anything fancy.

Comment: The compiler does not allow me setting next-text and previous-text to an empty string. But any way, the problem was solved using text instead of image. Thanks