# How to hide last page number in Angular pagination?

Tags: javascript, angular, pagination, ngx-pagination

I want to customise my pagination in angular, it should look something like this:

**<< < 1 2 3 ... > >>**

**<< < ... 7 8 9 ... > >>**

Is there any way to achieve this? I am using ngx-pagination but it is showing the last page number which I don't want. Please help.

Current scenario:

**< 1 2 3 ... 20 >**

Want this:
**<< < 1 2 3 ... > >>**

Comment: 1. Right-click on the last number and choose Inspect.  2. Note the class and parent class. 3. figure out the selector to access the last number in CSS. 4. Add the CSS.

Comment: it's difficult without know what "paginator" are you using :(

Comment: I am using pagination-controls directive @Eliseo

Comment: @mplungjan can't add css because am using pagination-controls directive here and it is taking total number of records and doing some inbuilt calculations to show the last page number by default in form of list
<li class="ng-star-inserted">
<a tabindex="0" class="ng-star-inserted">
<span class="show-for-sr">page </span>
<span>...</span></a>
</li>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424493/how-to-replace-pagination-previous-and-next-buttons-with-images-in-angular might help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved via custom-template. Here in the official docs example:
http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/custom-template

Here in the template, it loops thru the `pages` array.

```
<div *ngFor="let page of p.pages"
```

Since we don't want the last page, just cut it out of the array

```
<div *ngFor="let page of p.pages | slice: 0:p.maxSize - 1"
```

Final result[image]

Full working code could be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtusj7?file=app/app.component.ts

Edit:
As Eliseo pointed out in the comment, when the user move to the last page, that page number won't display in the navigation (as we removed it already). This's obviously not a good UX, so customize as your needs. Eliseo is generous enough to provide the solution too!

Comment: I feel that you should iterate over all and use a *ngIf in the "li with a":`<a *ngIf="p.getCurrent() !== page.value && (p.pages.length<=2 || page!=p.pages[p.pages.length-1] || p.pages[p.pages.length-2].label!='...')"><span>{{ page.label }}</span></a>`

Comment: Thanks Eliseo. Could you give the reason for using that instead of the current way?

Comment: You can not see the "10" event you're in the 10th page. Based in your stackblitz I try to do some look like in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usy887?file=app%2Fapp.component.html (I'm in hurry and it's not completed)

Comment: true story, thank you for pointing it out, but as you click 7th to reveal the rest, it will show last page (10th page) and therefore, against the requirement. I totally agree with you that the UX isn't good for now but let's just leave it for the author to decide